# Form validation in JAvascript with Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

I have a webpage with an input field where only digits are allowed.
The input field has an onkeyup event that starts this validating function:

```
function validate() {
    var uah_amount = document.getElementById("UAH").value;
    var allowed = /^\d+$/;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = document.getElementById("UAH").value;

    if (!allowed.test(uah_amount)) {
        document.getElementById("error").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Everything works as I expect until I hit Backspace button to remove some characters. In this case function always behaves as if I entered letters.

How to correct this?

Comment: Seems to be working well for me (rewrote it a little to change back to white when needed): http://jsbin.com/udowe3

Answer (score 0):

The function don't put back the background color if the test is passed sucessfully.

```
function validate() {
    var uah_amount = document.getElementById("UAH").value-0;
    var allowed = /^\d+$/;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = document.getElementById("UAH").value;
```

if (!allowed.test(uah_amount)) {
    document.getElementById("error").style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
   document.getElementById("error").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
}
}